# select command inside then in case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I got an error for the following query in SQL Server 2008

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

I want to use select command inside case statement after `THEN`

Below is the query

```
DECLARE @startTime DATETIME
    ,@endTime DATETIME
    ,@personId VARCHAR(max)
    ,@supplierId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NULL

SET @startTime = '2011-1-22'
SET @endTime = '2012-1-27'
SET @personId = '2dd3cd60-4acc-4ff1-9956-2938099c08af,69186022-78b5-4bc6-9878-55b14a44a5aa,e64f0bf8-51cc-4c85-a4bd-2615d3ba7a52,53091d8b-2891-4c46-babd-1f0036ffe003,ea21226c-8be6-48de-a707-fe0edd0b62a3,f5ce7a19-a8da-4c0c-a233-861f9330361b'

DECLARE @table TABLE (personId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)

INSERT INTO @table
SELECT deviceid
FROM [dbo].[Split](@personId, ',')

CREATE TABLE #tempTable (
    PERSON_ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    ,ASSET_ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    ,EVENT_TYPE_ID INT
    ,EVENT_START_DATE DATETIME
    ,EVENT_DATE DATETIME
    ,AMEND_TIME INT
    ,GRP INT
    ,SEQ INT identity(1, 1)
    ,ACTIVITY_TIME INT
    )

--Adding Raw data to TEMP table    
INSERT INTO #tempTable
SELECT ASSET_EVENT.PERSON_ID
    ,ASSET_ID
    ,Event_Type_id
    ,EVENT_START_DATE
    ,Event_date
    ,ISNULL(DATEDIFF(ss, event_start_date, Event_date), 0) AS INTERVAL
    ,0
    ,0
FROM ASSET_EVENT
INNER JOIN PERSON ON ASSET_EVENT.PERSON_ID = PERSON.PERSON_ID
WHERE event_type_id < 3
    AND EVENT_DATE >= @startTime
    AND EVENT_DATE <= @endTime
    AND ASSET_EVENT.PERSON_ID IN (
        CASE (LEN(@personId))
            WHEN 0
                THEN ASSET_EVENT.PERSON_ID
            ELSE (
                    SELECT deviceid
                    FROM [dbo].[Split](@personId, ',')
                    )
            END
        )
    AND ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(40), PERSON.SUPPLIER_ID), '') = CASE 
        WHEN @supplierId IS NOT NULL
            THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(36), @supplierId)
        ELSE ''
        END
ORDER BY person_id
    ,event_date

SELECT *
FROM #tempTable

DROP TABLE #tempTable
```

Any alternative for this query.

Comment: This part is the problem `SELECT deviceid FROM   [dbo].[Split](@personId, ',')`. This query return more than one row.

Comment: @Fireblade: ya i know, but whats the solution for this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your `select` query like this.

```
SELECT ASSET_EVENT.PERSON_ID,
       ASSET_ID,
       Event_Type_id,
       EVENT_START_DATE,
       Event_date,
       Isnull(Datediff(ss, event_start_date, Event_date), 0) AS INTERVAL,
       0,
       0
FROM   ASSET_EVENT
       INNER JOIN PERSON
               ON ASSET_EVENT.PERSON_ID = PERSON.PERSON_ID
WHERE  event_type_id < 3
       AND EVENT_DATE >= @startTime
       AND EVENT_DATE <= @endTime
       AND ( Len(@personId) = 0
             OR ASSET_EVENT.PERSON_ID IN (SELECT deviceid
                                           FROM   [dbo].[Split](@personId, ',')) )
       AND Isnull(CONVERT(VARCHAR(40), PERSON.SUPPLIER_ID), '') = CASE
                                                                    WHEN @supplierId IS NOT NULL THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(36), @supplierId)
                                                                    ELSE ''
                                                                  END
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit this line

```
and  ASSET_EVENT.PERSON_ID in ( CASE (LEN(@personId)) WHEN 0 THEN ASSET_EVENT.PERSON_ID ELSE (select deviceid from [dbo].[Split]( @personId , ',')) END )
```

to

```
and
(
    @personId = ''
    OR 
    EXISTS
    ( 
        select *from [dbo].[Split]( @personId , ',') 
        where deviceid = ASSET_EVENT.PERSON_ID
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Restructure that part of the `where` to be:

```
AND (LEN(@personId) = 0
    OR ASSET_EVENT.PERSON_ID IN (
        SELECT deviceid
        FROM [dbo].[Split](@personId, ',')
    )
```